# Does SagePay Server Integration support PayPal in iFrames?

Tags: iframe, paypal, opayo

Here's a quote from the Server Integration Protocol Documents:

> Sage Pay’s Server integration provides a secure, simple means of authorising credit and debit card transactions from your website. In addition, you can accept payments via PayPal...

There is nothing in **any public SagePay documentation** that says clearly that you can't use PayPal with the Server iFrame integration.

One of the main selling points of the Server integration is that it can be used in an iframe on the customer's site, and if PayPal cannot be integrated via SagePay server in an iFrame then this should be made clear at the point where the docs say that the Server Integration allows PayPal integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked today and in the actual documentation [Sage Pay Server Integration and Protocol Guidelines 3.00](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/12246/download-document/SERVER_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_010814.pdf) on Page 23 (5.0 Low Profile Payment Pages) there is a note confirming that PayPal is not supported for low profile payments (the one that use iframe).

> Please note that you will NOT be able to accept PayPal transactions or
>   Local European Payments with the Low Profile templates enabled.

Comment: Seems strange that they call it Low Profile Templates, instead of Server iFrame Templates, or they could call Section 5.0 "iFrame integration, - with Low Profile Templates"

Comment: @chim Yes is kind of strange, but not entirely.

Server integration can be done with and without iframe.

Without it, the process has more steps and you need to leave the e-commerce site, you can do some customizations, but you will notice that you are not on the original website. 

With iframe, you have to complete less steps and you are inside the e-commerce, you can customize it and give the sensation that everything happens inside of the site, so I guess the integration has a `low profile` and users doesn't notice the different.

Comment: :) Yeah, I think it's clear that we're agreeing that they could make it a lot clearer. The other question is why don't they support PayPal payments within an iFrame?  If you have a site that offers a subscription, and you want to offer PayPal as an option, then the user has to go off site to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not stated anywhere in SagePay's public documentation **The Server iframe integration doesn't support Pay Pal**.

Comment: Can you provide any public documentation to support this Rik? (The Server iframe integration doesn't support Pay Pal.)

Comment: can you add a link to avoid ambiguity and to help other people who visit this page please Rik.

Comment: I can confirm this answer is correct. Why they cannot add a "Pay by PayPal" button or link in the iframe with target="_blank" I do not know

Comment: You could use the Direct integration method - I know its not ideal, but you could break your checkout flow into a Paypal path, and a card payment path ....